# What is the best approach to duplicate the Google Calendar?

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api

What I'm trying to do here is create a Java program that will continuously sync all events from my Calendar1 to my Calendar2 EXCEPT for events under a certain condition (say I have marked as "maybe attend")

So far I've got some sample code up and running that allows me to connect to the Google Calendar via their SDK.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/

I've gotten as far as being able to read events from Calendar1. Great.

Now I'm trying to put them into Calendar2. The first approach I tried is using Events.Import

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/import

But I got the following error:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "calendar",
    "message" : "The owner of the calendar must either be the organizer or an attendee of an event that is imported.",
    "reason" : "participantIsNeitherOrganizerNorAttendee"
  } ]
```

It appears that the I can only import into the "primary" calendar I suspect.

So from here, what approach should I take? Should I be doing Inserts? The only problem there is the next time I sync, I won't know which events from Calendar2 to edit. I can get the incremental changes from Calendar1 from the [sync](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/sync) API. I just don't know how I would update Calendar2.

Comment: Better approach is to use events.import, but make sure to give iCalUID in the request https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/import